# How is a set partitioned into valid and invalid items using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

Is there a way to write a single LINQ expression to get the same result of the following code?

```
        var validations = new Func<conversion, bool>[] { 
             c => c.affiliate.affiliate_id > 0,
             c => c.campaign_id > 0
        }; 

        var invalidConversions = from c in extractedConversions
                                 where validations.Any(valid => !valid(c))
                                 select c;

        var validConversions = from c in extractedConversions
                               where validations.All(valid => valid(c))
                               select c;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you could use something like:

```
var partitioned = extracted.ToLookup(c => validations.All(valid => valid(c)));
```

Then:

```
// Valid conversions
foreach (var valid in partitioned[true])
{
}

// Invalid conversions
foreach (var invalid in partitioned[false])
{
}
```

You could use `GroupBy` as well, but `ToLookup` materializes the results immediately and gives you a handy way of accessing them, which I suspect is what you want here.

Comment: right, i don't know why I didn't see that myself - TooLookup moves each item into a bucket of the type which is the result of the function it receives... that's exactly what I wanted..

Answer (score 1):

If your `conversion` class has an overridden `Equals` and `GetHashCode` you might be able to do:

```
var validations = new Func<conversion, bool>[] {
   c => c.affiliate.affiliate_id > 0,
   c => c.campaign_id > 0
};

var invalidConversions =
    from c in extractedConversions
    where validations.All(valid => !valid(c))
    select c;

var validConversions =
    extractedConversions.Except(invalidConversions);
```